# How to delete all vpn connections

Tags: 16.04, openvpn

I would like to delete all saved vpn connections. I could delete them one-by-one (like shown in the imgage) but this would take forever as there are quite a few connections. Is there a fast way to delete them all in one go?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to

   ```
    cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
   ```
2. Remove the connections with this command

   ```
    sudo rm 3monkey*
   ```

This will remove all connections starting with name `3monkey`

3. Restart the network manager service

   ```
    sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```

Comment: don't forget to restart network-manager. `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

Comment: `/etc/Network-Manager/system-connections` is an invalid path. The correct path is `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Settings
2. Go to network Click on VPN Settings icon
3. Go to the details tab  (First tab)
4. Click remove VPN

   [image]